# Where to deploy large data for unit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

using Deployment in test configuration makes a copy every time the unit test is run which is time consuming. The data is a bunch of bitmaps that might change only after builds.

What's the convention for deploying such large test data?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are writing unit tests, it sounds like you are writing functional or integration tests...

Comment: I am unit testing an algorithm. Isn't this the correct terminology?

Comment: I could be wrong, but you might want to give more of a description of why* you need to load a large data set in order to run your test.  Explain what type of data it is.. file, database, etc and that will help us give you a better, more accurate answer.

Comment: Sure, it's a directory full of bitmaps.

Comment: Are you using a deployment item ?  Because that is designed to be "test" specific.

Comment: I enabled deployment and added the folder containing the bitmaps. What should I use instead?

Comment: Is the path static?
Would it work to put the path to the files in app.config (AppSettings), and just reference the path directly from the tests?

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote up a blog post about File Dependencies and testing here.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/how-to-run-integration-tests-with-file-dependencies/

The tests you are performing are integration tests since you are going to the file system.  I would use the example per class method in the post for what you are trying to achieve.

**Contents of Post**

Disclaimer

In many cases a developer test needs to execute with a specific file / set of files that need to be on the file system.  Many “purists” think this is a bad idea and you should “Mock” your system out in such a way that this is not required.  In certain cases that may be true – but I am a “realist” and understand that the complexity requirements around doing things like this can and many times do far outweigh the benefits from just leveraging the file system for the test.  This does however move the test from being a true “unit” test to an “integration” test.  I am content with this as it is also my belief that integration tests provide more value than unit tests.  If setup and run in the correct way – this test can run locally in visual studio, via MS build and the command line, or on a build server running build agents like Team City.

You can download the source code here: TestClass.zip

Requirements for this Test

Test Runner ( I like using TestDriven.Net as it lets me execute in line as well as debug). 
A file class that wraps some of the system.IO functions that allows you implement IDisposable. This is useful for creating a “sandbox” that once is out of scope – and it removes any temp files that are used so clean up is done automatically  (an example class is attached in the sample).
NUnit or MSTest.  I still prefer NUnit.
Usage Options
The requirements for the usage of the test files will determine how and when to set them up and clean up (delete).

Per Test – files are regenerated per test run against them
Per Test Class – files are generated once per test class
In both instances the FileSandBox class is used to create a temporary location for the files to live and then be removed once the test(s) are complete.

Per Class Usage

[TestFixture]
    public class PerClass
    {
        private FileSandbox _sandbox;
        private string _tempFileLocation;

```
    public PerClass() {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Setup class - runs once per class
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupClass()
    {
        _sandbox = new FileSandbox();

        // Getting Temp file name to use
        _tempFileLocation = _sandbox.GetTempFileName("txt");
        // Get the current executing assembly (in this case it's the test dll)
        Assembly myassembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        // Get the stream (embedded resource) - be sure to wrap in a using block
        using (Stream stream = myassembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestClass.TestFiles.TextFile1.txt"))
        {
            // In this case using an external method to write the stream to the file system
            _tempFileLocation = TestHelper.StreamToFile(stream, _tempFileLocation);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tear down class (cleanup)
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TearDownClass()
    {
        _sandbox.Dispose();
    }

    [Test, Description("Testing doing something with files on the filesystem")]
    public void MyFileSystemTest()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(_tempFileLocation);
        Assert.IsTrue(lines.Length > 0);
    }
}
```

Per Test Usage (Option 1)

```
 [TestFixture]
public class PerTest
{
    public PerTest(){}

    /// <summary>
    /// Setup class - runs once per class
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupClass()
    {
        // NOOP
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tear down class (cleanup)
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TearDownClass()
    {
        // NOOP
    }

    [Test, Description("Testing doing something with files on the filesystem")]
    public void MyFileSystemTest()
    {
        using (FileSandbox sandbox = new FileSandbox())
        {
            // Getting Temp file name to use
            string tempfile = sandbox.GetTempFileName("txt");
            // Get the current executing assembly (in this case it's the test dll)
            Assembly myassembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            // Get the stream (embedded resource) - be sure to wrap in a using block
            using (Stream stream = myassembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestClass.TestFiles.TextFile1.txt"))
            {
                // In this case using an external method to write the stream to the file system
                tempfile = TestHelper.StreamToFile(stream, tempfile);
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(tempfile);
                Assert.IsTrue(lines.Length > 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Per Test Usage (Option 2)

[TestFixture]
    public class PerEachTest
    {
        private FileSandbox _sandbox;
        private string _tempFileLocation;

```
    public PerEachTest() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Setup class - runs once per class
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupClass()
    {
        // NOOP
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tear down class (cleanup)
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TearDownClass()
    {
        // NOOP
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _sandbox = new FileSandbox();

        // Getting Temp file name to use
        _tempFileLocation = _sandbox.GetTempFileName("txt");
        // Get the current executing assembly (in this case it's the test dll)
        Assembly myassembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        // Get the stream (embedded resource) - be sure to wrap in a using block
        using (Stream stream = myassembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestClass.TestFiles.TextFile1.txt"))
        {
            // In this case using an external method to write the stream to the file system
            _tempFileLocation = TestHelper.StreamToFile(stream, _tempFileLocation);
        }
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        _sandbox.Dispose();
    }

    [Test, Description("Testing doing something with files on the filesystem")]
    public void MyFileSystemTest()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(_tempFileLocation);
        Assert.IsTrue(lines.Length > 0);
    }
}
```

You can download the source code here:  [Source Code](http://tsells.com.jasmine.arvixe.com/host/code/TestClass.zip)

Comment: Another thing - I would stored your images as a zip file - copy the file to location (temp) and extract there for usage.  It will run much faster than copying each of the files independently.